# Excel ISNUMBER to return matched Data

Tags: excel, range, match, vlookup

I have two (2) worksheets --

My data looks like this

Sheet 1

```
ID NAME
   Jon
   Bob
   Bill
   Lori
   Natalie
   Maria
```

Sheet 2

```
 ID     Title      NAME
   1    Mr.        Jon
   2    Reverend   Bob
   3    Dr         Lori
   4    Madam      Natalie
   5    Mrs.       Maria
```

I need a column in the first worksheet that looks up the name field in the range column in worksheet 2.

I got this working with the following code *(this was in worksheet 1 column B)*: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,Sheet1!D:D,0))`

What I need it to return is not TRUE/FALSE but the equivalent ID into the ID column.  I also have this *(worksheet 1 column A)* `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,Sheet1!C:C,0)),Sheet1!A:A,D2)`
but its returning the name instead of ID.

Comment: `=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!C:C,0))`?

Comment: What does this have to do with VBA? Try `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,Sheet1!C:C,0)),INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(D2,Sheet1!C:C,0)),"NOT FOUND")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the answer based on the comment by BruceWayne.

In cell B2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!D2,Sheet2!D:D,0))
```

[image]